# how to do the following in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to grab a string like

"/html/body/a"

i need to check the last portion, in this case "a" after the final "/"

how can i do this ? how can i regex match for the last item after the final "/" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = "/html/body/a"
x.split("/").last  # => "a"
```

Answer (score 4):

Regex?  Not sure, but what's wrong with

```
my_string.split("/").last # Maybe you want some error checking here, I don't know.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use regexp, this would be it:

```
mystring = "/html/body/a"
if mystring =~ /([^\/]+)$/
    last_part = $1
end
```